# Operation by indexing only last axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of 3 dimensional vectors. The dimension of the array is arbitrary: it could be a single (N×3), double (M×N×3), triple (K×M×N×3) etc. I need to operate on two components of the vector while preserving the other dimensions.

For example, if I know it is three dimensionsional, I could do the following:

```py
R = numpy.arctan2(A[:,:,:,1], A[:,:,:,0])
```

which gives me a three dimensional array of scalar values.

Now, to be able to do this on *arbitrary number* of dimensions. I need to slice over all other dimensions except the the last. So far, I'm able to do it with this:

```py
s = [numpy.s_[:]] * (len(A.shape)-1)
R = numpy.arctan2(A[s+[1]], A[s+[0]])
```

which works even for single vectors. Is there a more numpythonic way of achieving the above?

Comment: Indexing would be a better term in the title (rather than broadcasting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an even nicer way. This here works for me

```
R = numpy.arctan2(A[...,1],A[...,0])
```

Comment: That's it! I knew there was something like that built-in, but I have trouble navigating around the numpy docs. Sometimes the important information is in the user guide, other times it's in the reference… Ellipsis is mentioned in both though :p